# Splitting field of $\alpha=(2+\sqrt{2})^{1/3}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

Given $\alpha=(2+\sqrt{2})^{1/3}$ The problem asks to calculate the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ and find it's splitting field. I have the solution and I understood until the point where it shows that the minimal polynomial is $$x^6-4x^3+2=0$$
Now, since we got this polynomial developing the equation $\alpha=(2+\sqrt{2})^{1/3}$ it is clear that $(2+\sqrt{2})^{1/3}$ is a root of the minimal polynomial.

I don't understand the following: Why are $\left( 2-\sqrt{2} \right) ^{1/3},\left( 2-\sqrt{2} \right) ^{1/3}w,\left( 2-\sqrt{2} \right) ^{1/3}w^2,\left( 2+\sqrt{2} \right) ^{1/3}w,\left( 2+\sqrt{2} \right) ^{1/3}w^2
$ the other roots of the polynomial? $w$ is the cubic root of unity ($w^3=1$).

Comment: Should it be $x^6-4x^{\color{red}{3}}+2$?

Comment: If you have the list it is enough to evaluate the polynomial to verify that they are roots and checking that they are different. If you want to deduce that those are the roots you can call $y=x^3$, solve the quadratic equation that results to get $y=2\pm\sqrt{2}$, and then take cubic roots of its two solutions.

Comment: @Dave Yes, sorry, thank you for pointing it out. Fixed

Comment: @Doodle I undestand, thank you. What if I had $\alpha=\sqrt{1+2^{1/3}}$ and the minima polynomial $x^6-3x^4+3x^2-3=0$? Is it possible to get all the roots in an easy way like the one you explained?

Comment: The polynomial $x^6-3x^4+3x^2-3$ is a cubic in $x^2$, so I guess you could use the method for finding roots of a cubic.

Comment: You can find all the roots of any polynomial. However, it depends what you mean by find. For many, due to school conditioning find means express in a very restrictive form called 'in radicals'. In that case, then the polynomial has to be [solvable in radicals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_extension#Solvability_by_radicals).

Answer (score 2):

$$x^6-4x^3+2=0$$ $$\Leftrightarrow (x^3-2)^2=2$$
$$\Leftrightarrow x^3-2=\pm \sqrt{2}$$
$$\Leftrightarrow x^3=2\pm \sqrt{2}$$
$$\Leftrightarrow  x=\omega^i\sqrt[3]{2+\sqrt{2}},\omega^i\sqrt[3]{2-\sqrt{2}},i=0,1,2,$$ where $\omega$ is a root of $x^2+x+1$, so $\omega^3=1$.

Answer (score 1):

First, remember that if $\alpha$ is a (real or complex) root of $x^n-a=0$, $a\neq 0$, then the other roots are all of the form $\lambda^i\alpha$, where $\lambda$ is a **primitive $n$th root of unity**. That is, a complex number such that $\lambda^n=1$ but $\lambda^k\neq 1$ for $1\leq k\leq n-1$. This follows simply by noting that all of them are roots of $x^n-a$, they are all distinct, since $\lambda^k\alpha = \lambda^j\alpha$ implies $\lambda^k=\lambda^j$, and therefore that $\lambda^u=1$ where $u=|k-j|$. That means $n|k-j$, and so you get equality if both $k$ and $j$ are between $0$ and $n-1$.

Now, your polynomial is 
$$x^6 - 4x^3 + 2.$$
This is a quadratic polynomial in $x^3$. So you can easily find the two values of $x^3$ that are roots. Call them $a_1$ and $a_2$. So then you want to solve $x^3=a_i$, or equivalently find a root of $x^3-a_i$, $i=1,2$.

Since $Y^2 - 4Y + 2= 0$ has roots $2+\sqrt{2}$ and $2-\sqrt{2}$, then you want to find the solutions to
$$x^3 - (2+\sqrt{2})\qquad\text{and}\qquad x^3-(2-\sqrt{2}).$$
One root of the first is $\sqrt[3]{2+\sqrt{2}}$; so the three roots are $\sqrt[3]{2+\sqrt{2}}$, $\omega\sqrt[3]{2+\sqrt{2}}$, and $\omega^2\sqrt[3]{2+\sqrt{2}}$.

Similarly, since $\sqrt[3]{2-\sqrt{2}}$ is a root of the second polynomial, the other two roots are $\omega\sqrt[3]{2-\sqrt{2}}$ and $\omega^2\sqrt[3]{2-\sqrt{2}}$.